# Is there a way to increase function app timeout threshold from 30 minutes(default) to 2 hours ? We are in App Service plan

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I have an Azure function-app which is running in App Service plan. I do have long running processes which makes the host to go down (host gets shut-downed).

I have tried 2 approaches.

1. Changed the functionTimeout value in host.json to "02:00:00" - No luck
2. As per the below link and tried with functionTimeout as -1. Even here no luck. Still the function app host downs after 30 minutes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

Below is my host.json file content

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": -1,
  "queues": {
    "maxPollingInterval": 2000,
    "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
    "maxDequeueCount": 10,
    "batchSize": 10
  },
  "logger": {
    "categoryFilter": {
      "categoryLevels": {
        "Function": "Verbose"
      }
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "namespace": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

I expect function-app host timeout should be increased to 2 hours from its default 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this question has not been answered yet. I came across same situation where the app was ignoring values in host.json file.
Below solution worked for me(Azure Function App v2+):

1. Go to respective Function App.
2. Click on Configuration tab under Settings section from left hand side panel.(PFA)
3. Change the value of AzureFunctionsJobHost__functionTimeout(PFA)

Please not that there are some articles suggesting to update the functionTimeout value in local.settings.json, I tried but it doesn't work locally. But this solution works on server.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All logging settings now live under "logging". This means that the **"tracing" and "logger" have been removed**.

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "functionTimeout": "02:00:00",
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "namespace": "Information"
        }
    },
    "extensions": {
        "queues": {
        "maxPollingInterval": 2000,
        "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
        "maxDequeueCount": 10,
        "batchSize": 10
    }
}
```

Even with `Always On` enabled, the execution timeout for individual functions is controlled by the `functionTimeout` setting in the [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) project file.

For longer processing times, consider using the [Durable Functions async pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview#async-http) or [defer the actual work and return an immediate response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#avoid-long-running-functions).